# How to update Caliburn's SimpleContainer IoC registrations at runtime

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, caliburn

I've registered an instance of a service in Caliburn's BootStrapper's Configure() method and it injects properly.

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private SimpleContainer _container;

    // ...
    // other overridden functions
    // ...

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        _container = new SimpleContainer();

        // ...
        // window manager, event aggregator etc..
        // ...

        if (_runInDemoMode)
        {
            // run in demo mode against a mock service
            _container.Instance<IMyService>(new MyServiceMock());
        }
        else
        {
            // run with the real service implementation
            _container.Instance<IMyService>(new MyService());
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to update the dependency rule registration from within a ViewModel at runtime so that a user can swap between a real implementation of my service and a mock implementation without having to restart the application.

E.g.

```
public class SettingsViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    // ...
    // code
    // ...

    public void ChangeToDemoMode()
    {
        var container = IoC.GetContainer(); // <-- I made this up, how to do this?
        container.UnregisterHandler(typeof(MyService), key?); // <-- I don't know what the key would be
        container.Instance<IMyService>(new ServiceMock());
    }
}
```

As you can see I don't know how to get a reference to the container in order to fiddle with it, and I also don't know how to unregister the existing registration after I do reference the container. Is there a way to do this or will it tear the fabric of the IoC continuum?

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was to create a class with dependency on `SimpleContainer` this gives

```
public class CaliburnRegistrationService : IRegistrationService
{
    SimpleContainer _container;
    public CaliburnRegistrationService(SimpleContainer simpleContainer)
    {
        _container = simpleContainer;
    }

    public void Register(IResolver resolver)
    {
        // register you stuff based on interface implementation
    }
}
```

Then create IResolver implementations for each Mode of operation in your code e.g.`DemoResolver` and `RealResolver`

Then in Bootstrapper's Configure() do

```
_container.Singleton<IRegistrationService, CaliburnRegistrationService>();
_container.Singleton<IResolver, DemoResolver>(); // just some class that inherits from IResolver
_container.Singleton<IResolver, RealResolver>(); // just some class that inherits from IResolver
```

The by making the ViewModel dependent on `IRegistrationService`, it will allow you to call `Register` from the ViewModel.

And based on some parameters you can register your ioc container

```
public class SettingsViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
     IRegistrationService _registrationService;
     IEnumerable<IResolver> _resolver;
     public MyViewModel(IRegistrationService registrationService, IEnumerable<IResolver> resolver)
     {
         _registrationService = registrationService;
         _resolver = resolver;
     }

     public void ChangeToMode()
     {
           foreach(var resl in _resolver)
           {
                if(resl.ShouldRegister(.. some parameter..))
                {
                    _registrationService.Register(resl);
                    return;
                }
           }
     }
}
```

This gives you access to your IoC container anywhere